# Abseil C++ template argument

Tags: c++

I am looking here https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/blob/master/absl/types/span.h#L673

```
template <int&... ExplicitArgumentBarrier, typename T>
constexpr Span<T> MakeSpan(T* ptr, size_t size) noexcept {
  return Span<T>(ptr, size);
}
```

I do not understand this function. What is `int&... ExplicitArgumentBarrier` doing? 
It isn't used in the function so I am not able to figure out why its being used.

An example to show what 'trick' this is and why it is used would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Lookup variadic templates. Here's a starting point: http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#variadic-templates.

Comment: I know `variadic templates` - `ExplicitArgumentBarrier` is not being used in the function. I want to know why its being used.

Comment: It's to prevent people from putting explicit template arguments and therefore disabling template argument deduction.

Comment: @PYA, It's ok for a template parameter to be ignored in a function. For such cases, the user has to make the template parameter(s) explicit since they cannot be deduced from the arguments.

Comment: @RSahu i dont quite understand - how, according to you, should `MakeSpan` be called?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A common pattern you find in bad code is the usage of explicit template arguments in function templates which would otherwise perform template argument deduction, e.g.

```
std::make_pair<int,std::string>(1729, "Hello World!");
```

This is superfluous and in this case the explicit type for the second argument is even different from the type that would have been deduced.

To prevent people from doing so, you can just put a variadic bogus template argument in front of the argument which is to be deduced, so that nobody can ever explicitly name those arguments.

The developers apparently chose `int&...` as the type for the bogus argument but it could have been any other thing (another type as well) and to improve readability of the code they also gave it a name, `ExplicitArgumentBarrier`, which should make sense now.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment, you asked,

> i dont quite understand - how, according to you, should `MakeSpan` be called?

Here's a demonstrative program that does not use `MakeSpan`.

```
template <typename ... T, typename T2> void foo(T2 arg) {}

template <int ... N, typename T2> void bar(T2 arg) {}

int main()
{
   foo<int, int>(0);    // T2 is deduced to be int
   foo(0);              // T2 is still deduced to be int
   foo<int, int>(10.5); // T2 is deduced to be double
   foo(10.5);           // T2 is still deduced to be double


   bar<10, 20, 30>(1);   // T2 is deduced to be int
   bar(1);               // T2 is still deduced to be int

   bar<10, 20, 30>(1.2); // T2 is deduced to be double
   bar(1.2);             // T2 is still deduced to be double
}
```

A function call that involves `MakeSpan` would look like:

```
int a;
int b;
auto s1 = MakeSpan(20);        // T is deduced to be int
auto s1 = MakeSpan<a, b>(20);  // T is still deduced to be int
```

All the explicitly specified template parameters are ignored. The type of argument(s) is always deduced.

Comment: great - thank you, this really cleared things up for me :)